# Crystal Report Viewer Prompt Database Logon Failed While Navigating Next Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I tried to preview the crystal report by selecting values in dropdown list. It able to show 1st page without any problem. But when I tried to press Next Page button / typing in number of page, it will prompt out Database Logon Failed error.

I tried to google around about this issue and still unable to resolve the issue. Few threads similar to this issue I already go through but still no avail.

I inserted this logOnInfo function

```
        public void setLogonInfo()
        {
            TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "servername";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "databasename";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "user";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "pwd";

            TableLogOnInfos infos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            infos.Add(logOnInfo);
            crystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo = infos;
        }
```

I have Init() function too

```
        private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportDocument = (ReportDocument)Session["reportDocument"];
            crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        }
```

Lastly, this is the display report function when I clicked Search button

```
        protected void DisplayReport() // display all value selected
        {
            string customerID = this.ddwn_cust.SelectedValue;
            ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
            reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("rptSalesRep.rpt"));
            reportdocument.SetParameterValue("RepID", lblSalesRep.Text);
            reportdocument.SetParameterValue("CustomerID", lblcustomer.Text);
            reportdocument.SetParameterValue("ItemTypeID", txtItemType.Text);
            reportdocument.SetParameterValue("startdate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text));
            reportdocument.SetParameterValue("enddate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text));
            crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportdocument;
            setLogonInfo();
        }
```

**EDIT**
As for the postback section in Page_Load there, I tried few ideas but I still doesn't seems to get it right.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //my code
            if (!IsPostBack){
               if (Session["reportDocument"] != null)
               {
                  reportDocument =(ReportDocument) Session["reportDocument"];
               }
               crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument;
               crystalReportViewer.RefreshReport();
               }
```

Yet, I still unable to get to the next page of the crystal report viewer.

Any solutions to this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean navigate to next page? in crystal report itself?

Comment: yes the crystal report itself.

Comment: What happens on PostBack? Show the code. (You do know that Init will be called once and postback will also have an effect right?)

Comment: just a heads up.. sometimes crystal report returns that particular error due to wrong connection string, table name,fields and others.. It means unable to connect to database. I have a lot of experience regarding this issue and i encounter that error a lot.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch Wouldn't it be weird if I able to view the 1st page of crystal report but not the 2nd page and so on? I already checked the connection string and table name. It does not has any issue with it

Comment: check some parameters condition. Sorry i don't have your project and i wasn't able to help you more. I can't figure out the set up of your connection string and pulling of Data from your Database. Or maybe your code behind reload? on click next?